# How to store input values when moving to another component in react typescript functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React Typescript functional component like below,

```
const Comp = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [showNext, setShowNext] = useState(false);
  const [data1, setData1] = useState(array);

  return showNext ? <AnotherComponent /> : <></>;
};
```

If I move to the next component and coming back to the previous one, then state values are gone in the previous component. So, in UI already entered inputs are gone. How can I avoid this, or how can I store it?

Comment: Don't unmount the component, hide it

Comment: To expand on the comment above, passing in a `visible` property and letting the component handle hiding itself is a pretty common approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using conditional rendering you unmount the component depending on the state, unmounting component loses its state.

Therefore try hiding it with CSS **or** save its state in the parent component (`Comp` in this case)

```
// Save state in parent
const Comp = () => {
  const [nextState, setNextState] = useState({})

  return showNext ? <AnotherComponent {...nextState}/> : <></>;
};

// Or hide it with CSS
const Comp = () => {
  const [nextState, setNextState] = useState({})

  return <AnotherComponent className={showNext ? 'myClassName' : 'hideClass'} />;
};

// Possible CSS
.hideClass {
  display: none;
}

.myClassName{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: hiding class helps me. Thanks